# Multiselect ComboBox, Force it to always display the same text

Tags: wpf

I have a multiselect combobox that works fine. Except for the text. I want it to always have the same text ("Commodity Filter") regardless of what the user has selected.

If I set iseditable to true and the text to CommodityFilter it looks fine until the user makes a selection, then it is garbage (displays object type name). How can I hard code some text there? (Actually ideally i would databind it so it can change depending on whether anything is selected, but that would be a bonus at this point)

```
 <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Text ="Commodity Filter" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveCommodities}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                      Width="20" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Commodity}"
                                       Width="100" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: AFAIK, you will have to extract the template for the ComboBox and customize it to do this. Example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: The displayed text uses the same ItemTemplate as the drop down. It's showing you the object name instead of what you wanted because it doesn't know which property to expose in your complex object.

If you want to do what you are stating, then just overlay the combobox with another textbox.

Comment: @Xcalibur37 your solution (overlay the combobox with another textbox) is so obvious it hurts. I will post it as answer once I have it looking pretty. Unless something better comes along.

Comment: @PatFromCanada: Well, that or what code4life suggested would be fine. It really comes down to how you want to override the template. If you could see some reusability beyond your project code4life's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom object for populating the ComboBox (which had the `IsSelected` property and implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`) because I was creating several comboboxes to control filtering. Once I did this is was trivial to override the tostring on the customobject and pass in the appropriate text. So the xaml did not change much.

I would have preferred to overlay with a text box but that seemed to be beyond my abilities to get a polished look in a reasonable time.

```
   <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveFuturesMonths}"
               IsEditable="True"
               IsReadOnly="True"
               Text="Futures Month Filter" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                              Width="20" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                               Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the crux is in setting -
    IsEditable="True"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    Text="Futures Month Filter"

rather than creating custom object. thanks a lot it helped.